# An object reference is required for the non-static field, why?

Tags: c#

I did some research about this error, and all awnsers i found include removing static from the method or the property, but in my code there isnt any static, so i dont know whats happening, thanks for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class textoTitular : Form
    {
        public textoTitular()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void textoTitular_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            textoTitular.Text = "testing";   /// prints testing on the textbox
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are referring the class name (textoTitular), use "this.textoTitular" instead.

Comment: That does not work. new error Error 1 'WindowsFormsApplication1.textoTitular' does not contain a definition for 'textoTitular' and no extension method 'textoTitular' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.textoTitular' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you sure name of the textbox you are trying to set it's text is "textoTitular" (instead of for example textBox1) too?

Comment: @DanielBezerraDeMenezes if one of the answers bellowed provided solved your problem don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
private void textoTitular_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textoTitular.Text = "testing";   /// prints testing on the textbox
}
```

You are referencing the form class in a static way.

Rather try using `this`. Something like

```
private void textoTitular_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = "testing";   /// prints testing on the textbox
}
```

Added bonus, you can omit the `this` and use the object property

```
private void textoTitular_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Text = "testing";   /// prints testing on the textbox
}
```

Comment: _"prints testing on the textbox"_ suggests that he wants to assign text to a TextBox rather than the form.